# Spring Boot Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am using **Eclipse** Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0) and i have installed the 
**Spring Tool Suit(STS)** in eclipse for building Spring Boot Applications.

**Question**->
When ever I create new Spring Starter Project and try to maven build my project without any code addition. Build fails with below Error.

```
[WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) on project DemoSpringProject: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\SP064774\Util-Workspace\DemoSpringProject\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

If I remove the test folder which is having the default test. it work fine. But why this happens. Below folder is the one i deleted which generated by Spring boot project

```
src/test/java
```

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Below is the default test file which get generated.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DemoSpringProjectApplicationTests {

  @Test
  public void contextLoads() {
  }
```

}

Log from the refered file. C:\Users\SP064774\Util-Workspace\DemoSpringProject\target\surefire-reports

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.example.demo.DemoSpringProjectApplicationTests
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.473 s 

FAILURE! - in com.example.demo.DemoSpringProjectApplicationTests
contextLoads(com.example.demo.DemoSpringProjectApplicationTests)  Time 
elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name
```

'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': 
    Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested 
    exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error 
    creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource 
    [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/ 
    DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari .class]: Bean instantiation via factory 
    method failed; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to 
    instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 
    'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$ 
    DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver 
    class
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
    creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource 
    [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$ 
    Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested 
    exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed 
    to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 
    'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$ 
    DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver 
    class
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed 
    to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method ' 
    dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$ 
    DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver 
    class
    Caused by: 
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$ 
    DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver 
    class

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>DemoSpringProject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>DemoSpringProject</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: What does default test contain?

Comment: Updated the default Test

Comment: The warning about a profile named `pom.xml` not existing would suggest that there’s a mistake in the command you are using to launch Maven. What command are you using? Also, what do the files mentioned in the error message contain?

Comment: @Andy I am using clean install. And the file for with it is throwing this error is the one i have added in Update. Its auto generated Test class by spring boot. I have not added a single line of code

Comment: Ok, but what is the complete command you are using to run Maven? And it would still be useful to see the contents of the files mentioned in the error message that it suggests you refer to

Comment: @Andy i am using eclipse Run as Maven builld .. In that clean install.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I checked the fine it was refering to. I did understood much. I have added the content of that file in Updated section.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared your pom.xml file so I cannot be certain, but it looks like you don't have a database driver on the classpath. You'll either need to add a dependency on an embedded database (H2 or HSQLDB) or setup up a separate database such as MySQL or Postgres and add the appropriate driver as a dependency.

Comment: I have updated the pom. and yes H2 dependency was not there i tried mvn - clean install after but still the same issue.

Comment: While doing some research i got this link Git link. But i was not able to understand properly..
https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/8693

Comment: The problem discussed in that issue is specific to Debian-based Linux. You're using Windows so it is not relevant

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse go to Windows->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs and change path to jdk home folder

Answer (score 0):

Updating the jar plugin to 3.1.1 immediately fixes the problem:

```
<properties>
  <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16846#issuecomment-492792506