# maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1 test failing with NullPointerException

Tags: spring, easymock, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a problem successfully compiling my tests with maven. I am mocking a service using EasyMock v 4.0.2. I should mention running the test with the intellij IDE works without problems Below is the code attached. The problem seems to arise when ever I try to inject the mocks into my mock test. I have seen a couple of posts on this issue but nothing that addresses my problem.

The closest I have seen is this
[Spring Boot Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53663892/spring-boot-failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-plugi)

```
public class EasyMockExtension implements TestInstancePostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void postProcessTestInstance(Object testInstance, ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
        EasyMockSupport.injectMocks(testInstance);
    }
}
```

```
@ExtendWith(EasyMockExtension.class)
public class TestUserService extends EasyMockSupport {

    @TestSubject
    private UserService userService = new UserService();

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Mock
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Mock
    private MessengerRoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Mock
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Mock
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;


    @Test
    public void testAuthenticateUser(){
        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";
        String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        User user = TestUserHelper.createUserWithRoles(username, password);
        Collection<String> roles = user.getRoles().stream().map(MessengerRole::getRoleName).collect(Collectors.toList());
        EasyMock.expect(authenticationManager.authenticate(EasyMock.anyObject(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class)))
                .andReturn(EasyMock.anyObject(Authentication.class));
        EasyMock.expect(userRepository.findByUsername(username)).andReturn(Optional.of(user));
        EasyMock.expect(jwtTokenProvider.createToken(EasyMock.anyString(), EasyMock.anyObject(Collection.class))).andReturn(token);
        replayAll();
        Map<String, Object> authenticatedUser =  userService.authenticateUser(username, password);
        Assertions.assertTrue(MapUtils.isNotEmpty(authenticatedUser));
        Assertions.assertSame(authenticatedUser.get("token"), token);
        Assertions.assertTrue(((Collection<String>)authenticatedUser.get("roles")).containsAll(roles));
        Assertions.assertTrue(roles.containsAll((Collection<String>)authenticatedUser.get("roles")));
        verifyAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddFriendUsernameSuccess(){
        long userId = 10L;
        String username = "testUser2";
        User user = TestUserHelper.createUser();
        User friend = EasyMock.createMock(User.class);

        Optional<User> optionalUser = Optional.of(user);
        Optional<User>  optionalFriend = Optional.of(friend);

        EasyMock.expect(userRepository.findById(userId)).andReturn(optionalUser);
        EasyMock.expect(userRepository.findByUsername(username)).andReturn(optionalFriend);
        EasyMock.replay(userRepository, friend);

        User returnedUser = userService.addFriend(userId, username);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(returnedUser);
        Assertions.assertSame(returnedUser, user);
        Assertions.assertTrue(returnedUser.getFriends().contains(friend));
        EasyMock.verify(userRepository, friend);
    }
}
```

This is what I get from that. I would appreciate any help on this as I'm not sure why surefire is not injecting my mocks

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.messenger.service.TestUserService.testAuthenticateUser(TestUserService.java)

[ERROR] com.messenger.service.TestUserService.testAddFriendUserNotFound()  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.messenger.service.TestUserService.testAddFriendUserNotFound(TestUserService.java)

[ERROR] com.messenger.service.TestUserService.testAddFriendUsernameNotFound()  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.messenger.service.TestUserService.testAddFriendUsernameNotFound(TestUserService.java)

[ERROR] com.messenger.service.TestUserService.testAddFriendUsernameSuccess()  Time elapsed: 0.191 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.messenger.service.TestUserService.testAddFriendUsernameSuccess(TestUserService.java)

[ERROR] com.messenger.service.TestUserService.testAuthenticateUserUnableToFindUser()  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: EasyMockExtension is coming from where? Which line is line 207? (where the NPE occurs)

Comment: all the injected mock objects are the ones with NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

If the mocks are null, it means they are not injected correctly.

Where is `EasyMockExtension` coming from? It is not coming from EasyMock itself since JUnit 5 isn't supported yet. But would be happy to accept a contribution.

Comment: EasyMockExtension is an inherited class to enable support for Junit 5. I will update the question to include the class